How I can debug vscode webview javascript code with external debugger?
I know there is build-in developer tools, that can debug code and inspect dom tree, but is it possible to debug webview js code in external debugger?

you can start the: Webview Developer Tools from Command Palette
Use Source tab and set a breakpoint

yeah, I know. As I mentioned in question, I curious how to connect with EXTERNAL tool, not with build-in developer tools.

The web view debugger is the external tool, so to speak. No way to go more external for web views.
However, since you have a web app/web page for the web view, you could launch that outside of VS Code in a standalone browser and debug there. That's what I do with a vite SPA based on preact. Development is done in VS Code using an external browser. Then I do a production build and launch that in my extension.

Is your extension page depends on vs code integration? For example, I need to pass messages from extension host to webview and via-verse(using CustomDocument model in extension), so I can't run that in a browser.

That's independent. The extension part is debugged in the extension host. The webview part is debugged in a normal web app project which uses an external browser. I often build with maps, though, and debug the frontend part also in the extension project (using the webview dev tools, which then allows to use full preact code there too).
